# WebLogic WorkManager clustering/remote jobs

Tags: weblogic, workmanagers

Does WebLoogic WorkManager have the ability to execute jobs on other servers on the cluster to effectively parallelize jobs?

Answer (score 1):

There are two Work Managers - One on the server side that handles thread prioritization/queueing and the CommonJ Work Manager that can be used through the [CommonJ API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13733/toc.htm#i1058123).

Within your application, you can define priorities within the container and also pursue parallel execution on the same server. However, if you are looking to process workload in parallel across multiple servers by having a single application server splitting up its current workload and redistributing it across the cluster, the bulk of the logic will have to be written into your application.

WebLogic does provide other mechanisms to make this easier (For example, you could have a primary node process the workload into units of work and put it on a durable distributed topic that the other servers read from) but it would be easier to use an existing product, such as [Terracotta's EhCache](http://www.terracotta.org/products/enterprise-ehcache) or a compute cluster on [Oracle's Coherence Grid](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html).